# why Python auto cast int to tuple while define variable?

Tags: python, variables

I'm learning python, use w3schools python tutorial, read about how python **"Many Values to Multiple Variables"** and confused by the following Casting process.

```
>>> a=b,c=d = 1,2
>>> print(a,b,c,d)
(1, 2) 1 2 (1, 2)
>>> print(type(a),type(b),type(c),type(d))
<class 'tuple'> <class 'int'> <class 'int'> <class 'tuple'>
>>> x,y,z,t = 1,2,3,4
>>> print(type(x),type(y),type(z),type(t))
<class 'int'> <class 'int'> <class 'int'> <class 'int'>
>>> print(x,y,z,t)
1 2 3 4
>>>
```

**How type of a,d is 'tuple'?**

I thought they were 'int' when I study about it.

Comment: `1` and `2` are ints, sure, but that's not what you're assigning to `a` or `d`. Nothing's being cast, automatically or otherwise.

Comment: The tuple `1, 2` is the value being assigned.  There are three assignment targets: `a`, `b,c`, and `d`.  The first and last of those, being a single name, get the tuple directly; the middle one unpacks the tuple.

Comment: It is obviously impossible for an integer to be both 1 and 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the section 7.2 of the language reference, [Assignment statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements)

> An assignment statement evaluates the expression list (remember that this can be a single expression or a comma-separated list, the latter yielding a tuple) and assigns the single resulting object to each of the target lists, from left to right.

The first assignment statement

```
a = b, c = d = 1, 2

^     ^    ^    ^
|     |    |    +-- expression list
|     |    +-- target #3
|     +-- target #2
+-- target #1
```

consists of the expression list `1, 2` (which evaluates to a tuple) and three targets `a`, `b, c`, and `d`, which are assigned in the following order:

```
a = 1, 2
b, c = 1, 2
d = 1, 2
```

There is no casting involved. The assignments to `a` and `d` assign the tuple directly; the assignment to `b` and `c` pairs each target with a corresponding value in the tuple.

---

Perhaps most notably, it is *not* like in C where an assignment is considered an expression whose value is the value that was assigned. Something like `a = b = c = d` in C is equivalent to

```
/* C with explicit parentheses
 * d is assigned to c, with the value of c = d assigned
 * to b, and the value of b = c = d assigned to a
 */
a = (b = (c = d))
```

while in Python it is a single *statement* with the semantics defined above.

A common idiom in C is to use the value of an assignment in a conditional statement, so that you can bind the value being tested to a variable used later in the same statement.

```
while ((c = foo()) != bar) {
    printf("%s\n", c)
}
```

Prior to the introduction of the assignment *expression* in Python, the equivalent required a separate assignment statement before *and* in the `while` statement:

```
c = foo()
while c != bar:
    print(c)
    c = foo()
```

or more idiomatically, an infinite loop with an explicit break condition

```
while True:
    c = foo()
    if c == bar:
        break
    print(c)
```

With the assignment expression, you can now embed an assignment into a boolean-valued expression similar to the C example.

```
while (c := foo()) != bar:
    print(c)
```

Comment: I think python never casts anything if not explicitly told

Comment: Depends on what you consider casting. I think of Python as doing *no* casting: it never treats a value of one type as another type. Things like `str(3)` create a *new* `str` object rather than treating the existing `int` object as a string (though there are people who consider such conversions as another kind of cast). Things get murkier when you consider the `print` function (which implicitly calls `str` on its positional arguments) and conditional statements (which implicitly obtain a Boolean value when necessary). Still not a cast in my opinion, but I don't really consider it explicit.

Comment: Yes, by explicit i mean using `int(), float(), str(), dict(), list(), tuple()` and so on)

Comment: I find it interesting how the equal signs in the left-hand-side affect the assignment operation.

Comment: @wwii I'm not sure I follow. They don't really "affect" it in any way; they just induce *additional* assignments. For example, the presence of the `a = b, c = ` "prefix" doesn't affect the assignment to `d` in any way.

Comment: @chepner very detailed. Thank you. I'm learning from you guys 

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
a=b,c=d = 1,2
```

following happens

```
d = 1,2 # now d is 2-tuple
b,c=d # 2-tuple is unpacked, now b is 1 and c is 2
a=b,c # new 2-tuple a is created using b and c, now a is 2-tuple (1,2)
```

Comment: That's not how chained assignments work in Python.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is clearer when you add the `()` to surround tuples. This

```py
a = (b, c) = d = (1, 2)
print(type(a), type(b), type(c), type(d))
print(a, b, c, d)
```

is equivalent to

```py
a = b, c = d = 1, 2
print(type(a), type(b), type(c), type(d))
print(a, b, c, d)
```

So you assign a tuple `(1, 2)` to three targets `a`, `(b, c)` and `d` from left to right. `(b, c)` just [unpacks](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) the values so `b` is assigned the first and `c` assigned the last value of `(1, 2)`. All other variables i. e. `a` and `d` just get the tuple `(1, 2)` assigned.